# is there a way to use tracemalloc inside of a mutithreaded /multiprocess application?

Tags: python

I can't share code but when I import tracemalloc it works fine to profile memory for a single threaded Python application but when I start using frameworks that involve multiple threads, I get segfault error thrown. I suspect it is because tracemalloc is using too much heap memory inside each worker.

What I've tried: Yes, I've looked into guppy and memory_profiler but I can't seem to get any of them to work with my multihreaded application (or they don't easily measure peak memory). I tried tracemalloc because it easily gives peak memory. Guppy seems to have some problems installing with Python 3 and memory_profiler uses a decorator @profile where I can't seem to pass in include_children as a switch flag.

Comment: You might give [Scalene](https://github.com/plasma-umass/scalene) a try; it simultaneously does CPU, GPU, and memory profiling, works with multithreaded apps, and doesn't require decorators. Full disclosure: I am one of the primary authors of Scalene.